# Unique elements of a polynomial in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to get at the pairwise terms when you expand a product of sums in python.

e.g. expanding `(a1+a2+a3)(b1+b2+b3)(c1+c2+c3)` gives:

`a1b1c1 + a1b1c2 + a1b1c3+ a1b2c1 + ... + a3b3c3`

with 22 or extra terms.

I need to find a way to remove any elements of this expansion where the indices match (e.g. anything with a1 and b1, or b2 and c2).

Or in code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
c = np.array([6,7,8])

output = a.sum() * b.sum() * c.sum()
```

The I need to remove the terms `a[i]*b[j]*c[k]` where i==j, i==k or j==k.

For small vectors it's straightforward, but as these vectors get long and there are more of them there are a lot more possible combinations to try (my vectors are ~200 elements).

My boss has a scheme for doing this in Mathematica which does the algebraic expansion explicitly, and pulls out terms with matching exponents, but this relies very heavily on Mathematica's symbolic algebraic setup, so I can't see how to implement it in Python.

`itertools.combinations` give you a list of all such combinations, but this is really slow for longer vectors. I've also looked at using `sympy`, but this also didn't seem suited to very long vectors.

Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this in Python?

Comment: A first step could be to look at : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html
The return value from this is `out[i, j] = a[i] * b[j]`. So setting the diagonal to `0` and summing over gives the result needed for the first expansion. Not sure about the 2nd expansion though. Is there always 3 vectors of varying but equal dimension?

Comment: My first attempt at this was something very similar to this, but I also ran into trouble once you get past the 1st expansion. It's also trickier in that the number of vectors changes (it's a scheme for dividing half siblings into full siblings based on genetic markers, and you can't know ahead of time how many full sibships there should be).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Does this speed up your calculations?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
c = np.array([6,7,8])

combination = [a, b, c]
added = []

# Getting the required permutations
for p in itertools.permutations(range(len(a)), len(a)):
    # Using iterators and generators speeds up your calculations
    # zip(combination, p) pairs the index to the correct lists
    # so for p = (0, 1, 2) we get (a,0), (b, 1), (c, 2)
    # now find sum of (a[0], b[1], c[2]) and appened to added
    added.append(sum(i[j] for i, j in zip(combination, p)))

# print added and total sum
print(added)
print(sum(added))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But yeah, I tried this with vectors of length 100, and it was already having a hard time of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is faster than your current implementation, but by rolling a NumPy array (`special_sum` below) you can avoid terms which have duplicated indexes faster than the "obvious" implementation (`regular_sum`):

```
a = np.random.randint(15, size=100)
b = np.random.randint(15, size=100)
c = np.random.randint(15, size=100)

def regular_sum(a, b, c):
    n = len(a)
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                if i==j or i==k or j==k:
                    continue
                s += a[i] * b[j] * c[k]
    return s

def special_sum(a, b, c):

    # all combinations b1c1, b1c2, b1c3, b2c1, ..., b3c3
    A = np.outer(b, c)
    # remove bici terms
    np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)

    # Now sum terms like: a1 * (terms without b1 or c1),
    # a2 * (terms without b2 or c2), ..., rolling the array A
    # to keep the unwanted terms in the first row and first column:
    s = 0
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        s += np.sum(a[i] * A[1:,1:])
        A = np.roll(A, -1, axis=0)
        A = np.roll(A, -1, axis=1)
    return s
```

I get:

```
In [44]: %timeit regular_sum(a,b,c)
1 loops, best of 3: 454 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit special_sum(a,b,c)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: for vectors of 1000 my machine does `special_sum` in 22.8 seconds. Certainly a massive improvement!